# How many bridge hands contain exactly three aces or exactly seven diamonds, or both?

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

> How many bridge hands contain exactly three aces or exactly seven diamonds, or both?

I'm guessing that this problem is:

$$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$

So I start off by calculating $|A|$, or the combinations of exactly $3$ aces, then I pick the rest of the bridge hand:

$$|A| = {}_4C_3 * {}_{48}C_{10}$$

Then I calculate $|B|$, or the combinations of exactly 7 diamonds, then I pick the rest of the bridge hand:

$$|B| = {}_{13}C_7 * {}_{39}C_{6}$$

I then have to calculate $|A \cap B|$, which is where I'm lost.  I'm not sure how to do this.  I had a few guesses.

The first involves picking $3$ of the $4$ aces, then assuming one of the aces chosen was a diamond, picking 6 of the 12 remaining diamonds, then the rest of the cards:

$$|A \cap B| = {}_{4}C_3 * {}_{12}C_{6} * {}_{36}C_{4}$$

The second involves picking $3$ of the $4$ aces, then assuming one of the aces chosen was NOT a diamond, picking $7$ of the $12$ remaining diamonds, then the rest of the cards:

$$|A \cap B| = {}_{4}C_3 * {}_{12}C_{7} * {}_{36}C_{3}$$

I thought that maybe I'd have to add both of these cases to get $|A \cap B|$, but this is not giving me the correct answer when inserting these values into:

$$|A \cap B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$

Any help is greatly appreciated.  This problem has been challenging me for a day now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|A∩B|$ exactly 3 aces and exactly 7 daimonds.

I would break this into two cases... hands which hold the ace of diamonds, and hands that don't, and then add them together.

$1{3\choose 2}{12\choose 6}{36\choose4} + {3\choose 3}{12\choose 7}{36\choose 3}$

Comment: I'm confused why we wouldn't use the full 4 aces in the selections, it looks like you are only using 3 of the aces when choosing.

Comment: In both of your examples, if you add up the 3+12+35, you get 50.  Shouldn't they add up to 52?

Comment: Yes and no... yes, I had a mistake, but no they should sum to 51, because we are specifically accounting for the Ace of Diamonds, and there are only 51 more cards to allocate.

Comment: Couldn't they sum to 52 if your initial term was ${1\choose 0}$?

Comment: That would be a fair way of looking at it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I try to always make sure top values add to the total allowed items and the lower numbers result in the total items desired, it just helps me make sure I'm on the right track.

${1\choose 1}{3\choose 2}{12\choose 6}{36\choose4} + {1\choose 0}{3\choose 3}{12\choose 7}{36\choose 3}$

Thank you for all of your help.